# Is User Online?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am new to ASP.NET membership, and most solutions so far do not work for me.I want to implement a simple query that check if a user is online and returns boolean result.I am using ASP.NET Membership and profile provider.

```
Maybe a function like this:

    public boolean IsUserOnline(string userName)
{
    boolean result ={some query string here......}

    return result;

}
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Check if they are logged in, or if they recently accessed your website.  That's pretty much all you can do.  There's no Javascript or other function that will tell you if the user is sitting in front of your page reading it, or if the browser is closed.

Comment: Technically you could have a JavaScript timer invoke an Ajax request that would update the result of `Membership.GetUser().IsOnline() so that you at least know if the window is open (though certainly not that it's being viewed/used).  Practically, I can not imagine why I would go to that trouble.

Comment: All I wanted is to be able to show to users who's online like it's done everywhere facebook,yahoo,msn..name them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asp.NET membership does this for you:

```
Membership.GetUser(username).IsOnline
```

The length of time since the last request from the user to be considered online is available via the `Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` property.

Comment: Thanks A lot.That was so helpful

Comment: Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow default value of 20 minutes,is it accurate or I need to reduce this value ?

Comment: Its up to you.  Do you want to define a user as being online within a different time frame?  You can change this value in your membership provider configuration in web.config.